# cannot see intel AX200 wifi adapter in fresh ubuntu install

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

Just downloaded and installed latest Ubuntu Desktop and cannot see my wifi adapter. firmware is present in lib/firmware. Not a dual boot system.

The system sees the adapter but seems unable to load the necessary modules to get it running:

```
tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ sudo modprobe -fv >iwlwifi insmod /lib/modules/5.11.0-38-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko  modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Exec format error
```

From dmesg:

```
tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi [   
4.689170] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002) [    4.694805] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver [    4.694816] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22 [    4.695023] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm [    4.801910] iwlwifi 0000:05:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

So the AX200 is detected but not enabled and does not show up under iwconfig:

```
tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

enp6s0    no wireless extensions.
```

Kernel and OS:

```
tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ uname -a
Linux tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER 5.11.0-38-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 28 20:41:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

more adapter info:

```
tony@tony-X570-AORUS-MASTER:~$ lspci -nn | grep Intel
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? My Linux skills are fairly basic!  Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you are using 20.04, which is nearly two years old, and three releases removed from 'latest'. You are running an older 5.11 kernel, which indeed lacked AX200 compatibility. Try a newer kernel using https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thank you for that, I downloaded from Ubuntu website where this is the "standard" download. It seems that you can only download 21.xx via bit torrent if you look around.  Which is, well.......sh%t! Thanks again, saved me wasting another day!

Comment: So updated to 21.10 and still no wifi adapter available :(

Comment: What does this tell us? `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. So weirdly the issue, in the end, was that the PC was connected to the router via an ethernet cable, as soon as I unplugged the ethernet cable, the wifi adapter showed up. Pretty unexpected behavior in my opinion but there we go.